# how to extract last 4 characters of the string in SAS

Tags: sas

improved formatting,I am a bit stuck where I am not able to extract the last 4 characters of the string., when I write :-

```
indikan=substr(Indikation,length(Indikation)-3,4);
```

It is giving invalid argument.
 
how to do this?

Comment: To be more likely to get helpful answers, please include sample data that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This code works:

```
data temp;
indikation = "Idontknow";
run;

data temp;
set temp;
indikan = substrn(indikation,max(1,length(indikation)-3),4);
run;
```

Can you provide more context on the variable? If indikation is length 3 or smaller than I could see this erroring or if it was numeric it may cause issues because it right justifies the numbers (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245907.htm).

Comment: Use `substrn()` instead if you need strings of 3 characters or less to also be returned.  Also, if the string is empty, `substrn()` will handle this elegantly.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize substrn was so handy - I only knew about the null string return.  I'm not sure I understand why it's crammed full of other fun things, like better numeric handling and automatic truncation, but it's super handy @RobertPenridge!

Comment: @Joe Yeah I only just discovered it after looking at this answer as well.  Just like SAS to give the more useful function the less intuitive name =). I was actually checking the doc to see if regular `substr()` would accept a negative value as a start position (it doesn't) when I came across `substrn()`.  I definitely have some code to go and update now!

Answer (score 2):

If it's likely to be under four characters in some cases, I would recommend adding `max`:

```
indikan = substrn(indikation,max(1,length(indikation)-3),4);
```

I've also added `substrn` as Rob suggests given it better handles a not-long-enough string.

Answer (score 1):

Or one could use the reverse function twice, like this:

```
data _null_;

   my_string = "Fri Apr 22 13:52:55 +0000 2016";

   _day   = substr(my_string, 9, 2);
   _month = lowcase(substr(my_string, 5, 3));

   * Check the _year out;
   _year  = reverse(substr(reverse(trim(my_string)), 1, 4));

   created_at = input(compress(_day || _month || _year), date9.);

   put my_string=;
   put created_at=weekdatx29.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong results might be caused by trailing blanks:
so, before you perform substr, strip/trim your string:

```
indikan=substr(strip(Indikation),length(strip(Indikation))-3);
```

must give you last 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this approach, which, while initially a bit less intuitive, is stable, shorter, uses fewer functions, and works with numeric and text values:

```
indikan = prxchange("s/.*(.{4}$)/$1/",1,indikation);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data temp;
input trt$;
cards;
treat123
treat121
treat21
treat1
treat1
trea2
;run;

data abc;
set temp;
b=substr(trt,length(trt)-3);
run;
[Output]
```

Output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVB0A.jpg]